# Add a value next to a specific cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a program for a friend, who is working in a Human Resources department, that automatically sends letters of refusals to rejected applicants.

To have an overview of the application, he uses a spreadsheet where names, position, interviews, etc. are recorded. Every applicant has one row in the document.

If he rejects a candidate, he puts an "A" in a specific column. I want the program to recognize those "A"s, write an email to the applicant and then put the word "done" in the cell next to the "A".

The code is the following:

```js
function Absagen() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, 5);
    var endRow = range.getValue();
    var startRow = 1;
    var numRows = endRow;
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10)
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0];
        var absage = row[8];
        var absageSent = row[9];
        var mailLanguage = row[3];
        var gender = row[7];
        var firstName = row[5];
        var lastName = row[6];
        Logger.log("absage = "+ absage +" ?");
        if (absage == "A" && absageSent != "DONE" && mailLanguage == "2" && gender == "1"){
            var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
                              +"blablabla";
            var subject = "Ihre Bewerbung";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
            var destRow = Number(startRow); ++ destRow;
                sheet.getRange((destRow+i), 10).setValue("DONE");               
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial problem, that the "DONE" value was being written in multiple places, and later into the wrong rows, can be addressed by simplifying the code. Issues related to data type coercion (the String vs Number stuff from the comments on Serge's answer) can be avoided through the same simplification.

Here is the first thing that seemed confusing. You seem to be expecting cell `E1` to contain a number that will tell you how many rows to evaluate.

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 5);
var endRow = range.getValue();
```

*Then* you set `startRow=1`, and use that to read your data. When `i===0`, you set `firstName` to the content of cell `E1` again. Something isn't right. Either you'll get something that's not a number for `endRow`, or you'll try to process your headers. That might be OK for this particular function, but it would be best to use a pattern that you can reliably repeat.

Let's assume that the first row contains headers for the spreadsheet, and that all following rows contain relevant data that needs to be processed. The only data type coercion that may be left is in the comparisons for `mailLanguage` and `gender`, if the numbers for those values are forcibly entered as strings, or if the formatting for those columns is set to 'Plain Text'.

```
function Absagen() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headerRows = 1; // There are this many rows of header info
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();  // Range from A1 to last row & col with data
    var data = dataRange.getValues();  // 2-dimensional array from datarange

    // Start after header rows, process all remaining data rows
    for (var rowNum=headerRows; rowNum < data.length; rowNum++) {
        var row = data[rowNum];
        var emailAddress = row[0];
        var absage = row[8];
        var absageSent = row[9];
        var mailLanguage = row[3];
        var gender = row[7];
        var firstName = row[5];
        var lastName = row[6];
        Logger.log("absage = "+ absage +" ?");
        if (absage == "A" && absageSent != "DONE" && mailLanguage == 2 && gender == 1){
            var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
                              +"blablabla";
            var subject = "Ihre Bewerbung";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
            // Range for update is at (rowNum+1) because the _array_ starts at 0,
            // but sheet rows start at 1.
            sheet.getRange((rowNum+1), 10).setValue("DONE");               
            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Mogsdad, this was indeed a "poisoned gift" as it was supposed to be sooo simple and finally leads to a very long comment exchange that I had on my phone, without the ability to test anything... let's hope your code will clarify a bit ;-) , anyway it's more 'academic' than my "local repair" ^^

Comment: guys, thank you so much for the help - it finally works. As I said, I'm a complete beginner with all that, I don't even get the code you suggested completely, but as long as it works, I'm fine with that :).

Comment: @user2615229 - added comments to explain, I hope that helps you understand better, and makes it easier to re-use.

Answer (score 0):

This script shouldn't be too hard to debug if you use the logger to see intermediate values (see example in code below) and if you change a bit your condition (even if I have no idea what is supposed to be the "blabla nothing important" ;-)

```
Logger.log('absage = '+absage+' ?');
if (blaba, nothing important && absage == "A" && absageSent!='DONE'){// prevent sending multiple time and send only if "A" and if 'nothing important !
    var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
                      +"blablabla";
    var subject = "Ihre Bewerbung bei Westwing Home & Living";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
    var destRow = Number(startrow); ++ destRow;
    sheet.getRange((destRow+i), 10).setValue("DONE");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

---

**EDIT after this looooong serie of comments.** 
As I said, using the logger would have helped you to see what happens. I finally copied your code in a SS to test and it took less than a minute to see the issue.
Here is the modified code and the logger that goes with it. Look at it carefully and you'll see what was happening.

```
...
var destRow = Number(startRow)+Number(i);
  Logger.log(startRow+' '+i+' '+(startRow+i))
  Logger.log(startRow+' '+i+' '+(Number(startRow)+Number(i)))
sheet.getRange(Number(destRow), 10).setValue("DONE");
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the 'sheet.getRange(startRow+i+1, 10).setValue("DONE")' line still doesn't work, like this simply nothing is written in the cells next to the As. I also tried it with startRow+i without +1, and then the program does exactly what I, but 10 lines below the actual cells, where I want the As.

Comment: see edited code , the parenthesis should solve this... you had 11 instead of 2 because 1+1 was interpreted as 11 instead of 2.

Comment: See new update, Number() should do the job. Btw, have a look at row 101 in your sheet, you should find the first series of result for the same reasons I mentioned above :-) You coud also log the value startrow+i+1 to confirm how it is interpreted.

Comment: thanks for your patience - but still the same problem, "DONE" is written in line 101 and 121..

Comment: Use Number on the sum as we'll ... and use the logger to control the result. May be it would be easier to use a new var ... I'll suggest a new version

Comment: okay, what is happening now is, that "DONE" is written in the cell J3, regardless of where "A"s are.

Comment: oooops, sorry. was +i and not +1... just a typo ;-)

Comment: okay so now the "DONE" appears correctly, but 20 lines below the actual position they supposed to be.

Comment: Could you please post your updated code in an edit of your question?

Comment: and another update that might be helpful: if I leave the "++ destRow;" part away, then "done" is 10 instead of 20 lines below the right position.

Comment: That is clearly a wrong interprétation of the number taken as a string... try to add i before the getRange.